# Neukirch Corollary 11.7

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of Corollary 11.7 in Neukirchs ANT.

Here, he states that the group of S-units of an algebraic number field $K$ can be decomposed as the roots of unity in $K$ and a free abelian group, i.e. $ K^S = \mu(K) \times \mathbb{Z}^{|S| + r+ s -1}$.

In the proof, he firstly states that the torsion subgroup of $K^S$ is the group of roots of unity in $K$. How does one see this?

What I've seen so far is :

$o_k^S = \{f/g : f, g \in o_k, g \notin \mathfrak{p} \forall \mathfrak{p} \in S\}$ and
$(o_k^S)* = \{f/g: f, g \in o_k, f,g \notin \mathfrak{p} \forall \mathfrak{p} \in S\}$.

Therefore, I should somehow (how does it work formally?) be able to reduce to $o_k*$ and there it should be easier to show that the torsion subgroup are the roots of unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an element $a \in K^S \subseteq K$ is torsion then $a^k = 1$ for some $k$ so $a$ is a root of unity.   If $a$ is a root of unity, it is integral over $K$ and so is in $o_K \subseteq K^S$.